# v2.4.2 Enemy Levels

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that previously enemies would level up with you as you leveled. Is that still the case. Is it possible to know the approximate level of monsters you fight?

Presumably the enemy levels would scale according to the Torment level in some fashion. However the torment scaling tables I have looked at only display damage and health, nothing about levels.

*This would be handy for gauging resistances, my barbarian has >100% resistance to, well everything that can cause damage. However it does state that this is only for level 70 monsters. Given I do in fact take damage still.. <s>one would have to surmise that the enemies are above level 70; by how much is unclear.</s> or that the resistance calculation is multiplicative and not additive. **This means a tooltip with 89 + 20 isn't a total of 109 but instead 91.2***

Comment: What context are you using to state that your barbarian has > 100% resistance everything that can cause damage but only for monsters at level 70?

Comment: @ChaseC Most likely the tooltip in-game that says "X resistance to monsters at level Y" when you hover over the specific resistance.

Comment: @ChaseC Indeed I was using the tooltip as Frank suggested. After your answer below clarified that the enemies were level 70 there clearly had to be another answer. I found it and edited the question appropriately.

Comment: In Diablo 3 elemental resistance can never be more than 100%, or even 100%. Formula for resistance percentage from elemental resistances is DR = Res / (Res + 5*mlvl), i.e. for level 70 monsters 350 resistance will give you 50% reduction, 700 resistance - 66% reduction, 1050 resistance - 75% reduction and so on. Can you please provide a screenshot with that ">100%" you mention?

Comment: @OrcJMR continue reading the paragraph, or read the comments under.

Comment: @Josh I did. After discussion in comments your question still says your barbarian has over one hundred percent resistance - is it now false? It also says that "a tooltip with 89+20 is 91.2" which is also something that I never saw in game and don't really understand. The tooltip I see says things Frank mentions, with a formula I described.

Comment: @OrcJMR At the time I wrote that I believe my actual resistances were around 81%. The information in the question is merely example data.

Comment: @Josh It is quite strange to write "my barbarian **has** *[impossible and false things]*" and call it an example...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The blue arrow in this image is where you can view the game level of monsters in your game. The 70 represents the level of all monsters in the game.

There is no approximating because all monsters will scale to this level as it changes as you level up in game.

Higher difficulties do not matter in regards to monster level, it just adds monster % buffs.